# Specifying textarea background color with React.CreateElement

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a plugin (a widget kind of deal) for an application. It's an Electron-based application, and I'm injecting the widget with React.CreateElement, like so:

```
const e = React.createElement;
class myWidget extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return e('p', {}, 'Hello world!');
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to inject a textarea like so:

```
const e = React.createElement;
class myWidget extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return e('textarea', { style: { backgroundColor: 'white' } });
    }
}
```

And this adds the textarea. But the background of the textarea is see-through, and not white, which makes it really ugly.
If I look at the element, I can see that the attribute has been applied (`<textarea style="background-color: white;"></ta>`), but to have a white background, I need to manually edit that (from the inspector) to have an `!important` (so it'll be `<textarea style="background-color: white !important;"></ta>`).
I've searched for how to pass `!importants` to React, but they don't let you. What can I do about this?

Edit: 
I guess I found a solution, but it's really hacky. I'm inserting a div with a size of 1px * 1px which will stretch to the size of the textarea child. It works, I guess, but if anyone has a proper solution I would love to hear.

```
e('div', { height: '1px', width: '1px', style: { backgroundColor: 'white' } },
    e('textarea', { style: { minWidth: '100%', maxWidth: '100%' } })
)
```

Comment: your textarea style maybe overrided from a global css, otherwise the above code should work

Comment: It could very well be, but I have no control over those things. I'm injecting my snippet into another page. My snippet should be loaded after, though.